# Request of references regarding Friedman's Nobel Prize

Tags: macroeconomics

I've been trying to find the work for which Friedman was awarded the Nobel prize in economics. Does anybody know what was he awarded the prize for and where can you read the original paper?

Answer (score 4):

> The Royal Swedish Academy of Sciences has decided to award the 1976 Prize in Economic Sciences in Memory of Alfred Nobel to Professor Milton Friedman, University of Chicago, Illinois, USA, for his achievements in the fields of consumption analysis, monetary history and theory, and for his demonstration of the complexity of stabilization policy. [...]
>   His major work, A Monetary History of the United States,1867 - 1960, is regarded as one of Friedman's most profound and also most distinguished achievements. Most outstanding is, perhaps, his original and energetically pursued study of the strategic role played by the policy of the Federal Reserve System in sparking off the 1929 crisis, and in deepening and prolonging the depression that followed. The critics agree that this is a monumental scientific work which will long stimulate the re-examination of the course of events during this epoch.

http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/economic-sciences/laureates/1976/press.html

Comment: so he won the Nobel for a 800 + pages book that has a co author?) I've read this explanation in the Nobel prize website. I was hoping for something more concrete. or maybe he was given like generally. he has done many stuff lets give him the Nobel?)

Comment: I don't know if there is anyone who got an economic Nobel for one single paper.

Comment: heard of Nash?)

Comment: You mean the father of Nash-equilibrium and the Bargaining Solution and some other concepts? Who also happened to share the prize?

Comment: yes. he won for just one paper.

Comment: Oh. So I guess the bottom of the [Nobel press release](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/economic-sciences/laureates/1994/press.html) is a lie then. Is Harsanyi real?

Comment: it's one paper) that's my point. not for multiple works, or a book) and Nash shared it yes but why Milton got it (just himself) for a book if it has a coauthor, probably because the coauthor didn't do something that is worthy, if so then what did Milton do precisely ?))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56617/discussion-between-danny-nelson-and-denesp).

Comment: @denesp Ronald Coase got it for **two** papers, The Nature of the Firm (1937), and The Problem of Social Cost (1960). He barely wrote anything else. That is maybe the best you can get :)

Comment: Let's hope the OP doesn't get too curious about what won Tirole the Nobel, for their sake...